# Why do I need to remove old files first when upgrading Drupal or its modules?

Tags: updating, files

I'm in the process of updating my Drupal version 7.41 to 7.43 and started o follow the guide [Update procedure (minor version change)](https://www.drupal.org/node/1223018;) where it says

> 3. Remove all old core files and directories, except for the 'sites' directory, the original install profile in the 'profiles' directory and any custom files you added elsewhere.

and I was wondering why they wanted to have me erasing everything first, can't I just copy all the new content into my ftp folder except the `sites/` directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By deleting all the directories you're ensuring no files are left over that shouldn't be there anymore. A simple overwrite won't always do that.

Comment: right, true, true...